# How to reguraly send data to a BLE peripheral on a IOS (swift) app in background?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Im quite new to iOS programming and i'm working with Core Bluetooth in Swift 3 to connect and exchange data to a specific (custom made) ble peripheral.

If the user selects a specific mode in the aplication i need to send data (write characteristic) to the device on a regulary interval (each minute) or on a specific time even if the user opens another app or turn the screen off. If the app is active i can achive this with a scheduledTimer but it stops as soon as the app became inactive. There is any way to continue to send data to the peripheral if the app goes to foreground? Is this possible?

**Edit**

This is my Background Modes (as described by Deepak Tagadiya):
[Background Modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJdan.png)

And below some code from my controller:

```
class MyDevice: UIViewController {

var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
var selectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
var mRXCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?
var mTXCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?
var auto_timer = Timer()


@IBOutlet weak var AutoSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBAction func AutoSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if(sender.isOn == true){
            activateAutoModeTask()
        } else {
           disableAutoModeTask()
        }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)   
    (…)
}

func activateAutoModeTask(){


    auto_timer.invalidate() // just in case this button is tapped multiple times

    // start the timer
    auto_timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTask), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func disableAutoModeTask(){
    auto_timer.invalidate()
}

func updateTask(){
    let new_value = getNewValue() //function that get the new value


    send(text: new_value)
}

func send(text aText : String) {
    (…)
    self.selectedPeripheral?.writeValue(data, for: self.mRXCharacteristic!, type: .withResponse)
}
```

}

extension MyDevice: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    (…) 
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    (…)
    peripheral.delegate = self
    selectedPeripheral = peripheral
}
```

}

extension MyDevice: CBPeripheralDelegate {

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    (...)
}


func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    (…)
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    (…)
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    (…)

    responseReceived(response: response_text)
}
```

}

So i'm able to write to the peripheral if the app is active but not when the app goes to background (if i click on Home button for example). Maybe something is still missing...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it isn’t possible to initiate the transfer from the central (your app) on a timed basis when it is in the background. Your peripheral could issue a notify every minute that would trigger your app which could then write a value.

Comment: after 3 minute you app is not in alive mode so this is not possible.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you give me some documentation or something were i can find the information that supports your anwser?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue and resolved it by doing this.
Enable Background mode features according to your requirements from capabilities.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry Pooja Gupta but can you be more specific please? Because i already enabled the BackgroundMode for "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" but i believe this works if the peripheral sends for example a notification (that can wake up the app) but doesn't work in the other way around..

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Open project.
2. Select Target(Below the Project).
3. Go To ‘Capabilities’ Tab.
4. Select ‘Background Modes’.(By default it is off)
5. Select ‘Uses Bluetooth LE accessories’ and ‘Act as a Bluetooth LE accessory’(Both).
6. Run Project.
   [image]

Comment: Hi Deepak, thanks for your anwser but i'm still stuck on this. I have updated my question, can you give me some feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in special steps and only when you control peripheral too.
Make message to peripheral with delay info to next wake up.

In foreground you send it to `peripheral = wakeme=30s`
App go background and wait. After 30s peripheral asks for data and send some own data plus next delay...